# JTable very slow

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jtable

I have a JTable in a swing application.  I wrote a quick and dirty un-dock operation where the JTable is removed from its default parent and gets added to a seperate JFrame.  When the JTable is undocked and placed on a seperate JPane it is REALLY slow at moving around in the JTable... as soon as I dock it back into its original place, it's back to acting normal again... below is the code for the undocker..
any ideas?
thank you

JTABLE UNDOCKER

```
public class MatrixWindowUndocker implements ActionListener{

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(
        MatrixWindowUndocker.class.getName());
MatrixVerifier mv;

public MatrixWindowUndocker(MatrixVerifier mv)
{
    this.mv = mv;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    undockMatrixPanel(mv);
}

private static void undockMatrixPanel(MatrixVerifier mv)
{
    JFrame undockedFrame = mv.undockedWindowFrame;

    undockedFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(
            WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    locateFrame(undockedFrame);

    mv.mainMatrixTablePanel.remove(mv.mainMatrixTableScrollPane);
    undockedFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    undockedFrame.add(mv.mainMatrixTableScrollPane);
    mv.pdfAndMetadata_JPanel.remove(mv.table_pdf_splitter);
    mv.pdfAndMetadata_JPanel.add(mv.pdfDrawCanvasPanel);
    mv.pack();
    mv.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    undockedFrame.pack();
    undockedFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    mv.undockedFrame = undockedFrame;
    undockedFrame.setVisible(true);
}

private static void locateFrame(JFrame frame)
{
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = null;
    GraphicsDevice[] gds = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
    logger.debug("gds.length: " + gds.length);

    if (gds != null && gds.length > 1)
    {
        gc = gds[1].getDefaultConfiguration();
    }
    else
    {
        gc = gds[0].getDefaultConfiguration();
    }
    frame.setLocation(10 + gc.getBounds().x, 10 + gc.getBounds().y);
}
```

}

JTABLE DOCKER

`public class MatrixWindowDocker implements ActionListener
{`

```
MatrixVerifier mv;

public void setMv(MatrixVerifier mv)
{
    this.mv = mv;
}

public MatrixWindowDocker(MatrixVerifier mv)
{
    this.mv = mv;
}

/**
 * Main action method.
 * @param e
 */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    dockMatrixPanel(mv);
}

private static void dockMatrixPanel(MatrixVerifier mv)
{
    if (mv.undockedFrame != null)
    {
        mv.undockedFrame.dispose();

        mv.pdfAndMetadata_JPanel.setAlignmentX(0.8F);
        mv.pdfAndMetadata_JPanel.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(550,
                0));
        mv.pdfAndMetadata_JPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800,
                0));
        mv.pdfAndMetadata_JPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        mv.table_pdf_splitter.setDividerLocation(.60);
        mv.table_pdf_splitter.setDividerSize(2);
        mv.table_pdf_splitter.setResizeWeight(0.3);
        mv.table_pdf_splitter.setDividerLocation(0.50);

        mv.pdfAndMetadata_JPanel.add(mv.table_pdf_splitter,
                java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        mv.table_pdf_splitter.setLeftComponent(mv.pdfDrawCanvasPanel);

        mv.mainMatrixTablePanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
        mv.mainMatrixTableScrollPane.setViewportView(mv.metadataTable_JTable);

        mv.mainMatrixTablePanel.add(mv.mainMatrixTableScrollPane,
                java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mv.table_pdf_splitter.setRightComponent(mv.mainMatrixTablePanel);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rudimentary profiler included in the JDK from JDK 1.6, I think called jvisualvm.  You might try using it to see what's going on.  Even better would be a real profiler, but the only good ones are for-pay although some have 30 day free trials.